# How to run application only for 2 months after installation

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing `WPF application`, i want it to run only for `2 months after the installation`.

How to get the installation date once the application installed on the computer.? Is it possible in WPF app.?

Comment: What should happen after that period? Close the application? Don't allow to start it again? Is it some kind of trial software?

Comment: Yes its a trial software.I want to display a message after 2 months.

Comment: If you're happy with my answer please accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Easiest is to check the last write date of the application itself.
When installing the application the last write date is set to the current date.
In your application you can do something like that (just typed in the browser, might have small typos):

```
if(File.GetLastWriteTime(Application.ExecutablePath) < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2))
{
    // Show message and then close the application
}
```

Be aware that this is not really a safe check. A user can easily change the LastWriteDate of the application and then use it again.

**Update:**

Changed the file name from *"MyApp.exe"* to *Application.ExecutablePath*

Comment: Thanks for the response.But i didn't know about the File Path while installing the app.How i would get the Path of the application.?

Comment: Is there any other way to check..?

Comment: Application.ExecutablePath, will return the path of the running application

Comment: @JamesBond I am not getting Application.ExecutablePath .

Comment: What do you mean, you don't 'get' the application path? Is it an empty string or does not build anymore? Do you have an `using System.Windows.Forms;`at the top of the file?

Comment: If this is an acceptable approach (and mind you, this is really not great for trials because i can simply switch the clock on my computer and run this again), then a better option would be to timestamp your assemblies (define a custom attribute for that) and then read this via reflection at runtime. if you strongname your code then they can't tamper with this timestamp.